# close console window in wpf application

Tags: wpf, console, window

My wpf application processes orders. I want to see how my program works in console window but at the end I want user to press any and close console Window. I try:

```
    private void pobierz_zamówienia_button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AllocConsole();
        Encoding encoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(MY_CODE_PAGE);
        var hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        var hRealOut = CreateFile("CONOUT$", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, FileShare.Write, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (hRealOut != hOut)
        {
            SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, hRealOut);
            Console.SetOut(new StreamWriter(Console.OpenStandardOutput(), Console.OutputEncoding) { AutoFlush = true });
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Zakończono pobieranie zamówień, naciśnij dowolny klawisz");
        Console.ReadLine();
        FreeConsole();
    }
```

But after pressing any key console window is still opened.

Comment: Does it stay open after pressing 'Return'? `Console.ReadLine()` is expecting to read a whole line. If you want to press any key `Console.ReadKey(true)` is probably what you are looking for.

Comment: That's not the point. Even if I comment this line /// Console.Readkey(true) console window is still open.